# Editing Powershell Object

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell to run a command like so:

```
$getlist=rclone sha1sum remote:"\My Pictures\2009\03" --dry-run 
Write-Output $getlist
```

that outputs a object with the results. Problem being I only want the first column of those results. I've tried things like custom-format --Depth 1 and the other *-format commands but they don't work on this object??

[image]

Comment: It seems like you want `$getlist.foreach({($_ -split '\s+')[0]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that outputs a object with the results

While that is technically true, it is more specifically an `[object[]]`-typed *array of lines* (`[string]` instances) that assigning the *stream* of output lines - produced by the external `rclone`  program - to a PowerShell variable implicitly created. (Arrays created by PowerShell are `[object[]]`-typed, even if all the elements are of the same type, such as `[string]` in this case).

**PowerShell fundamentally only "speaks text" when communicating with external programs.**

Therefore, to extract *substrings* from these lines you must perform *text parsing*, as implied by [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings)' comment on the question.

A simplified approach is to use the *unary* form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split):

```
# Simulate lines input whose first whitespace-separated token is to 
# be extracted.
$getlist = 'foo bar baz', 'more stuff here'

$getlist.ForEach({ (-split $_)[0] })
```

The above yields:

```
foo
more
```

[zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66404192/45375) shows a simpler alternative that relies on the [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operator's (among others) ability to operate directly on *each element* of an *array*-valued LHS.

However, the `-split` approach is useful if you want to extract *multiple* column values.

---

**If you don't need / want to capture all of the external program's (`rclone`'s) output in memory first**, you can **use *streaming* processing in the *pipeline***, via the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet:

```
'foo bar baz', 'more stuff here' | ForEach-Object { (-split $_)[0] }
```

Note: While slightly slower than collecting all lines in memory up front, the advantage of a pipeline-based approach is reduced memory load: only the extracted substrings are kept in memory (if assigned to a variable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1) to remove the undesired parts of the output:

```
$getlist = $getlist -replace '\s.*'
```

When a PowerShell operator such as [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator) is applied to a collection, it will be applied to each element individually, creating a new array that stores the results (see [Substitution in a collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators?view=powershell-7.1#substituting-in-a-collection)).

The regular expression removes everything from the first whitespace up to the end of the string.

RegEx breakdown:

- `\s` - a single whitespace character like space and tab
- `.*` - any character, zero or more times